# Use of "in" with ablative

Tags: vocabulary, idiom

I'm hoping someone can clarify the meaning of the medieval Latin phrase "in ipsa" when referring to a decision or action not being "in" or "upon" someone, which I assume means that the decision isn't theirs to make?  Here's the sentence: ""Quae Johanna iterum respondit quod in ipsa non erat hoc facere ; et, si in ipsa esset, hoc esset bene cito factum."

Answer (score 5):

We would need more context (especially the text before your quotation) to be sure. But my preliminary reading would indeed be that she felt it was not "up to her" to do it. Needless to say, the expression would not be written this way in classical Latin.

Comment: In the text before this quote, she says she didn't have any advice or permission on the matter, and it wasn't "in ipsa", then she repeated that in the quote I already gave above.

Comment: @CeeGesange: Perhaps posting more of the Latin text in your question might help.